# How can I add only a file to zip and not the folder path leading to it in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, zip

I'm using the code below to zip a backup file that is created daily.

```
import os, zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("Test.zip", "w")
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/Bob/Desktop/Zip"):
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(root, filename))
zf.close()
```

The problem is that when I open the zip, it includes all the folders in the path leading to the file. For example, inside the zip, I would have a folder called Users/Bob/Desktop/Zip/File.gdb

But I ONLY want the File.gdb inside the zip. The reason is because when it includes all these folders, it doesn't actually compress the file. It is the same size it is when it's not inside the zip. But if I only zip the File.gdb it does from 30Mb to 3Mb.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which are you asking about, file name or compression? They are entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to look at [`arcname` parameter of `ZipFile.write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.write):

> `ZipFile.write(filename[, arcname[, compress_type]])`
>
> Write the file named `filename` to the archive, **giving it the archive name `arcname` (by default, this will be the same as `filename`**, but without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed).

In your case, you most likely want:

```
zf.write(os.path.join(root, filename), filename, zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: Thanks! That did work, but for some reason it still doesn't actually compress the file like it does when I right click the folder and Send To zip through Windows. Any idea why I'm not getting any compression?

Comment: The pathname has nothing to do with the compression. You aren't getting compression because you aren't asking for it. Try: `zf.write(os.path.join(root, filename), compress_type=ZipFile.ZIP_DEFLATED)` or `zf.write(os.path.join(root, filename), filename, ZipFile.ZIP_DEFFLATED)`.

Comment: Thanks. That also worked except the Zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED should have a lowercase Z, so zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED.

Comment: Thanks again to both of you for the help.